# How to handle concurrent request in python for a specific function?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, solr

I am using `python flask` project as a api backend for my ecommerce website and `Solr` is a product-search and search-suggestion layer in my website, When customer type anything in the search box my frontend(`react Js`) it will call an API for every charecter and the API get request from the http call then it will make a query and do search in solr then it will return the matching keywords as a http response.

My Issue : Concurrent http calls causing delayed response for the search suggesion.

Route

```
@routes.route('/Search/suggest',methods=['POST'])
    def Suggest():
        search_response = ProductSearchController().SearchSuggest(request.get_json(force=True))
        return search_response
```

Conroller

```
def SearchSuggest(self,request):
        try:
            keyword = str(request['keyword'])
            final_suggesions = []
            print("########################### START ##################################" + str(request['keyword']) + " start =====>")
            print(datetime.now())

            brandStatus, brandResponse         = self.solrHelper.getBrandSuggestion(request)            

            catSubCatStatus, catSubCatResponse = self.solrHelper.getCategorySubCategorySuggestion(request)
            
            productStatus, productResponse     = self.solrHelper.getProductSuggestion(request)
            
            modelStatus, modelResponse         = self.solrHelper.getModelSuggestion(request)
            
           
            print(" ########################## END ############################# "+str(request['keyword']) + " end <=====")
            print(datetime.now())            

            ####### some solr response validation goes here #########

            response_data = SuccessResponse(final_suggesions)

        except Exception as e:
            track = traceback.format_exc()
            app.logger.error('Server Error: %s', (e))
            app.logger.critical(track)
            return False, response_data
        finally:
            return True, response_data
```

Output Log

```
########################### START ##################################cr start =====>
2020-09-05 05:32:56.706340
########################### START ##################################cri start =====>
2020-09-05 05:32:56.944722
########################### START ##################################cric start =====>
2020-09-05 05:32:57.157928
########################### START ##################################crick start =====>
2020-09-05 05:32:57.368213
########################### START ##################################cricke start =====>
2020-09-05 05:32:57.605466
########################### START ##################################cricket start =====>
2020-09-05 05:32:57.786270
 ########################## END ############################# cr end <=====
2020-09-05 05:32:58.056129
 ########################## END ############################# cri end <=====
2020-09-05 05:32:58.497315
 ########################## END ############################# cric end <=====
2020-09-05 05:32:58.717623
 ########################## END ############################# crick end <=====
2020-09-05 05:32:58.902956
 ########################## END ############################# cricke end <=====
2020-09-05 05:32:59.198349
 ########################## END ############################# cricket end <=====
2020-09-05 05:32:59.206024
```

As you can see in the log, User type `cricket` in the search box. Concurrent http calls happening happens here, So before getting the result of the first letter next sequence calls fired to the same function, Please suggest me the better solution for this process.